# SQL Date Issue for Weekly Report Data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need to run a weekly report based on the arrival date. How can I set the arrival date in the where clause so that I can get the result only for each week. The hard part is I DO NOT want to modify the dates each week. I need the permanent where clause for the date. I have to provide a list of customers who arrived every week and I just want to run the same script without changing the week dates.

Please assist.
Thanks.

Comment: google for getdate and datediff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 
(ARRIVAL_DATE>DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()-7), MONTH(GETDATE()-7), DAY(GETDATE()-7)))//7 days before starting at midnight
AND 
(ARRIVAL_DATE<DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), DAY(GETDATE()))) //NOW in the YYYY, MM,DD format
```

Comment: I am wondering if I need to include "ARRIVAL_DATE<GETDATE()" .

Comment: if you are sure all arrival datees in your DB are in the past then no

Comment: I tried this and it is printing the records for the current day as well. Example: I want to print records from Dec 18 to Dec 25, which will be one week. However, it prints records for Dec 26th also. Can you please help more. Thanks.

Comment: fixed it with DATEFROMPARTS function (available SQL Server 2012+)

Comment: Date seems to have been fixed. I got results from Dec 19 to Dec 25, a week. How can we fix the time? Can it get records from midnight to midnight for 7 days?

Comment: that is actually seven days (19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25). what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Date is fine now but the problem is with the time. If I run the script today (Dec 26) at 2pm, it fetches the records starting from Dec 19 2pm. The list is missing records before 2pm on dec 19.

Comment: Did not work. It gave me records from 1996-12-20 01:26:00.000
to 2014-12-20 23:56:00.000 instead of 2014-12-19 00:00 to 2014-12-25 23:59*.

Comment: what did you type exactly? bcz looks like you typed year(getdate())-7 and not Year(getdate()-7)

Comment: I confirmed and that doesn't work. It includes 20 yrs old records instead of just this year, month, and week.

Comment: sorry, should be ARRIVAL_DATE > in the first one. please try the updated solution now

Comment: That did the trick. I didn't realize the < sign. Can I ask you just one more favor. How about if I want to run the script monthly? I have another thread open if you can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657759/weekly-to-monthly-reports

Comment: I have the below script for monthly report. Does it look like the best solution? I am having the right results bt just trying to confirm.  
SELECT Column1,...
FROM TableName
WHERE
MONTH(DateColumn) = MONTH(dateadd(dd, -1, GetDate()))
AND
YEAR(DateColumn) = YEAR(dateadd(dd, -1, GetDate()))

Comment: yes, this will load all the data for december 2014 if you run it with today's date

Answer (score 0):

This will get everything that happened in the current calendar week (Mon-Sun)

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE ArrivalDate BETWEEN
CAST(DATEADD(dd,(((DATEPART(dw,getdate())+@@DATEFIRST) % 7)+5) % 7 ,getdate()) as date) AND
CAST(DATEADD(dd,6+((((DATEPART(dw,getdate())+@@DATEFIRST) % 7)+5) % 7 ),getdate()) as date)
```

Edit - Removed extra E in BETWEEN

Comment: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'BETWEEEN'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near 'DATEPART'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near 'DATEPART'.

Comment: Thanks Lee. Gabriel's code worked so I am using that.