# Weekly to Monthly Reports

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I was running weekly reports as in the below script. However, I now want to run monthly report so needed some assistance.
Weekly:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 
(ARRIVAL_DATE>GETDATE()-7)//7 days before
AND 
(ARRIVAL_DATE<GETDATE()) //NOW
```

For monthly report, will below script be right if I run on every 1st?

```
SELECT Column1,...
FROM TableName
WHERE
MONTH(DateColumn) = MONTH(dateadd(dd, -1, GetDate()))
AND
YEAR(DateColumn) = YEAR(dateadd(dd, -1, GetDate()))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic looks okay, although I would use `day` instead of `dd`, because I think it is clearer.

However, your query will prevent the use of an index on `datecolumn`.  The following is a "better" form of the logic, because it allows the use of an index:

```
where datecolumn >= dateadd(month, -1,
                            dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), cast(getdate() as date))
                           ) and
      datecolumn < dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), cast(getdate() as date))
```

This looks more complicated, but all the functions are on `getdate()`, so the engine can use an index.  Also note the explicit conversion to `date`.  `getdate()` returns a time component which might throw off the logic if `datecolumn` only has a date.

Comment: It says "'day' is not a recognized built-in function". I am using sql server 2012.

Comment: `day()` is definitely a function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176052.aspx) as well as an option to `dateadd()`.  I think the messed up parentheses were causing the error.

Comment: This prints the results starting from 2014-12-20. It doesn't show any records between 2014-12-01 to 2014-12-20. I need all the records for the month. Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: @Bulbul . . . This should get all the records from the month before the date the query is run.

Comment: This gave me result only from 2014-12-26 to 2014-12-29.

Answer (score 0):

where datecolumn between `dateadd(mm, -1,getdate()) and getdate()`

Comment: That will get records from 2014-11-29 to 2014-12-29. I just want everything from Dec only. For now, I will just use the script I have in my question. It works so not a big deal.